# What situation uses this syntax: thing.Foo().Bar(this)

Tags: c++11, syntax

Can someone show me an example of where this syntax would show up in code?

```
thing.Foo().Bar(this)
```

From the looks of it, I see an object that calls a function that calls another function?

I obviously don't know how it works. If you have the slightest idea, I would appreciate a suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could be found in any non-static member function of a class. The `Foo()` function of `thing` returns an object of a class with a member function `Bar` that takes a pointer to the current object (`this`) as argument.

Comment: By the way, your answer made perfect sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you really intend to return a copy of the `ClassA` object in `ClassB::Foo()`? - if so, this that's fine.

Comment: @marko That's a good question. I neglected to make ClassC inherit from ClassA. This way ClassA will be passed a pointer to an instance of ClassC. It's quite confusing, but it's something I would like to experiment with. I believe it will be the key to a project I'm working on.

Comment: The rookie mistake everyone makes when starting out with OO programming is to overuse Inheritance.  You're often better off with composition.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm actually trying to limit inheritance. How does composition help here?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of many possible scenarios:

```
struct somethingelse
{
    void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        thing.Foo().Bar(this);
    }
};

struct foo 
{
    void Bar(somethingelse *pSomethingElse);
};

struct thing
{
    foo &Foo() {return m_foo;}

    foo m_foo;
};
```

What makes this a bit unusual is that the naming convention for the class and method naming is the opposite of the de-facto one in which classes are capitalised and methods camel-cased.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you for your contribution.